# How to split a JSON file into separate files using Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

I have a large json file that contains thousands of objects

```
{
    Desc: 'ABC',
    Arguments: [ 'Trace' ]
},
{
    Desc: 'XYZ',
    Arguments: [ 'Stack' ]
},
```

I'd like to split this json file so that each json file contains a single document, and name them with value:

ABC.json, XYZ.json,

For example, ABC.json will contain:

```
{
    Desc: 'ABC',
    Arguments: [ 'Trace' ]
}
```

I want to implement using typescript, Any suggestions.

Here is my incomplete code.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const file = 'test.json';
const jsonData = mapEvents(getJSONFileData(file));

function getJSONFileData(filename) {
  return fs
    .readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8')
    .split('\n')
    .filter(Boolean)
    .map(JSON.parse);
}

function mapEvents(events) {
  return JSON.stringify(events);
}
const objects = JSON.parse(jsonData);
objects.filter(function () {
  return "Code" === "";
});

    for(const fname in objects){
        fileName = objects['Code']+'.json'
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data is an array initially, I think you're doing too much.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const file = 'test.json';
const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file).toString());

// loop over every entry
data.forEach(record => {
    // save as record.Desc for the name. I'm not sure what you want to stringify
    // so I just put record there, perhaps you want record.Arguments
    fs.writeFileSync(`${record.Desc}.json`, JSON.stringify(record));
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for you reply,with the above code getting error with forEach not a function so have added into Object.keys(data).Can you please tell me how to add fileName with value accrodingly.When i run the code file is not creating,Getting json data with separate object as a response instead of creating file

Comment: Can you console.log(data); and tell me what the structure looks like? Based on your question it starts with `[...` so this should of worked.

Comment: `{ Data: { Desc: "ABC", Arguments: [ 'Trace' ] } }, { Data: { Desc: "XYZ", Arguments: [ 'Stack' ] } } `  Whole object data getting into single,I need to get each object create into separate file with the value accordingly.

Comment: Let me exaplin my requirement again ,`{ Data: { Desc: "ABC", Arguments: [ 'Trace' ] } }, { Data: { Desc: "XYZ", Arguments: [ 'Stack' ] } } ` Expected output is ABC.json should have `{ Data: { Desc: "ABC", Arguments: [ 'Trace' ] } }` and XYZ.json should have `{ Data: { Desc: "XYZ", Arguments: [ 'Stack' ] } }`

Comment: I don't think that's valid JSON, maybe you might be able to do something like this: `const data = JSON.parse('[' + fs.readFileSync(file).toString() + ']');`